# Custom UITableViewCells not showing correct data from UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have a custom `UITableViewController` which has passed to it an `NSArray` containing `NSArrays` containing `NSDictionarys`. For now (until I get this working) the `NSDictionary` objects just have "id" and "value" elements.

- The `UITableViewController` uses a custom `UITableViewCell` which for the time being only has a label in it.
- Also, for the sake of simplicity for the time being, all the `NSDictionary` objects contain only numbers for the "value" so I can track what's going on easier. So array[0][0] has "1-1", array[1][0] has "2-1" and counting up.

**The Problem:**

The table rows are sized such that I can only see 3 rows initially. When I scroll the 4th row is displayed correctly with "4-1". However, while following the code I noticed that the 5th row is not initialized properly.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"] autorelease];

    NSDictionary *temp = [tmp objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"value"];
    cell.delegate = self;
}
```

I noticed that the "cell" object does not come back nil and is already initialized. It displays "1-1" in the label instead of "5-1".

Anybody have any idea why? I wouldn't think it has to do with the same cell identifier names being used.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs to be something like this:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"] autorelease];

    cell.delegate = self;
}

NSDictionary *temp = [tmp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.descriptionLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"value"];
```

I'm assuming `tmp` is an array and you want the value from the array based on the cell's `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Weird! I changed nothing and just moved the code around as you recommended and it seems fine.
Why is it that having the code so that only the custom cell initialization and the assignment of the delegate in the if block and everything else outside of it allows this to work properly?

Comment: Cells get reused. Anything about a cell that is different for each row must be set outside the `if` statement. Anything that is the same for every row can be set in the `if` statement.